# How to get xlm macro sheet from excel with apache poi XSSFWorkbook?

Tags: excel, vba, apache-poi, xssf

I want to get macro sheet and remove it from xlsm document. Excel contains Macro1 and Sheet1.

`workbook.getNumberOfSheets()`

This returns 1, just Sheet1. It doesn't recognize Macro sheets.

```
for part in workbook.getRelationParts():
    print(part.getDocumentPart())

result:
Name: /xl/macrosheets/sheet1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.ms-excel.macrosheet+xml
Name: /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.worksheet+xml
Name: /xl/theme/theme1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml
Name: /xl/styles.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.styles+xml
Name: /xl/sharedStrings.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sharedStrings+xml
```

If i remove macrosheet relation document is corrupted.

```
opcpackage = workbook.getPackage()
macro = opcpackage.getPartsByName(Pattern.compile("/xl/macrosheets/.*.xml")).get(0)
opcpackage.removePart(macro)

wbpart = workbook.getPackagePart()
wbrelcollection = wbpart.getRelationshipsByType("http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/xlMacrosheet")

for rel in wbrelcollection:
    wbpart.removeRelationship(rel.getId())

workbook.write(outstream)
```

Do you know any solutions to find and remove macrosheets?

Comment: Seems like the POI removeRelationship may not be working in this case. The POI community is not very active, so it might be worth trying something else. xlsx/xlsm files are in zip format. You can use Java zip package to unzip the files (or use commons-compress jar). You can then remove the files in xl/macrosheets/ directory. You will also need to edit the XML xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels to remove the refs to the macrosheet files you removed. You can then zip up the updated files. Java has in-built APIs for all this.